# Trying to model a legacy database using rails, receiving Table Doesn't Exist error

Tags: mysql, ruby, legacy

I am trying to use rails to model a legacy database.  I have successfully modeled several tables without issue, however, I have one that I can't model.  Here's one that works:

```
mysql> describe symbols;
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| symbol              | varchar(40)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| company_name        | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| company_description | varchar(2048) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| exchange            | varchar(40)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the model code:

```ruby
class Symbols < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Here is the rails console output:

```
>> Symbols
=> Symbols(symbol: string, company_name: string, company_description: string, exchange:      string)
>> Symbols.count
=> 5980
```

Now here is the table that doesn't work:

```
mysql> describe cgp;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| symbol | varchar(40) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| val    | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the model code:

```ruby
class Cgps < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "cgp"
  set_primary_key "symbol"
end
```

Here is the rails console output:

```
=> Cgps(Table doesn't exist)
>> Cgps.count
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Table 'smdata.cgp' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `cgp`
```

I'm stumped.  I have tried variations trying to call the class "Cgp" instead of "Cgps" as well.  I have destroyed and reconstructed the model several times without success.  I have other tables that work perfectly.  This table doesn't work.  It's such a simple table, what could be going wrong?  I'm successfully overriding the pluralization and taking care of the fact that there is no "id" column.  Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: is CGP in the same database? if not, look at set_database_name

Comment: Yes it is.  I tried your suggestion anyway.  Here is what it gave me at the rails console:  >> Cgps
NoMethodError: undefined method `set_database_name' for Cgps(Table doesn't exist)

Comment: You did rake db:migrate this right ? If you access the DB console, do you see your table ?

Comment: It says `Table 'smdata.cgp' doesn't exist` I don't know anything about mysql, but it looks to me like it's confused about what schema the table is in.